# Scan a specific file in a directory

Tags: php, function, class, web

How to scan a specific file in a directory without specifying a specific path?

I need it for the spl_autoload_register so I don't need to specify all my folders.

I need to specify all 3 paths so the function will search on those given path "server_global_script_path", "server_login_script_path", and "server_plugin_script_path". But I want is the function will just search all my directory to search the script?

Example:

```
spl_autoload_register( function ( $class_name ) {
    $configurations            = $GLOBALS[ 'configurations' ];

    $root_path                 = $configurations[ 'root_path' ];
    $server_global_script_path = $configurations[ 'server_global_script_path' ];
    $server_login_script_path  = $configurations[ 'server_login_script_path' ];
    $server_plugin_path        = $configurations[ 'server_plugin_path' ];

    $class_files[]             = "{$root_path}{$server_global_script_path}{$class_name}.php";
    $class_files[]             = "{$root_path}{$server_login_script_path}{$class_name}.php";
    $class_files[]             = "{$root_path}{$server_plugin_path}{$class_name}.php";
    $class_file_included       = false;

    foreach ( $class_files as $class_file ) {
        if ( file_exists( $class_file ) ) {
            if ( require_once( $class_file ) ) {
                $class_file_included = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $class_file_included == false ) {
        shutdown_application();
    }
} );
```